# Does the singular locus of a conical variety (or scheme) determine the singular locus of its projectivization?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Lets say $X$ is a conical affine algebraic variety (conical meaning $X$ is the zero set of homogeneous polynomials of positive degree, equivalenty $X \subsetneq k^n$ and $x \in X \Rightarrow ax \in X$ for all $a \in k$) and $\mathbb P(X)$ is the projectivization of $X$ (the projective variety defined by the same homogeneous equations as $X$).

Clearly the origin $0 \in X$ is a singular point.  If $a \neq 0$ is a nonsingular point of $X$ then is the line through $a$ a nonsingular point of $\mathbb P(X)$?

More generally, if $A$ is a graded Noetherian ring generated in degree $1$, and $\mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Proj} \ A$ is a homogeneous prime ideal such that the point $\mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec} \ A$ is regular, then is $\mathfrak p$ regular in $\mathrm{Proj} \ A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes (and is if and only if) in the general case. Indeed, let $f\in A$ be a homogeneous element of degree $1$. Then we have a canonical isomorphism 
$$ A_{(f)}[T, 1/T] \simeq A_f$$ 
(see proof below). Now choose such an $f$ with $\mathfrak p\in D_+(f)$. Denote by $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, $Y=\mathrm{Proj}(A)$ and $x\in X$ (resp. $y\in Y$) the point corresponding to $\mathfrak p$. 
Then $O_{X,x}$ is a localization of $O_{Y,y}[T,1/T]$, hence flat over $O_{Y,y}[T,1/T]$. Thus $O_{Y,y}\to O_{X,x}$ is flat, and the regularity of $O_{X,x}$ implies that of $O_{Y,y}$ (see Matsumura, Commutative Algebra, 21.D, Theorem 51).

More globally, let $m=\oplus_{d\ge 1} A_d$ be the irrelevent ideal. Note that the above isomorphism for various $f$ implies that the canonical morphism 
$$\mathrm{Spec}(A) \setminus V(m) \to \mathrm{Proj} A$$ 
is smooth (even a $\mathbb G_m$-bundle).  If $y$ is regular in $Y$, then any point of $X$ lying over $y$ is regular.

**Edit**

If $X$ is the affine cone over a field, then the above isomorphisms says that 
$$X\setminus \{ 0\} \simeq \mathbb P(X)\times \mathbb G_m$$ 
Zariski locally on $\mathbb P(X)$. If the field is algebraically closed, the regularity at closed points can be checked with Jacobian criterion, and the if and only if statement is clear (without invoking flatness).

**End of Edit.**

Now let us prove the above isomorphism. The homogeneous localization $A_{(f)}$ is a subring of $A_f$. Define $\phi : A_{(f)}[T]\to A_f$ by taking $T$ to $f$. It induces canonically a ring homomorphism $\phi: A_{(f)}[T,1/T]\to A_f$ because $f$ is invertible in $A_f$. As $f$ has degree $1$, it is easy to see $\phi$ is surjective. Suppose $\phi(\sum_{k} b_k T^k)=0$ with $b_k\in A_{(f)}$ (the sum is a finite sum in $k\in\mathbb Z$). There exists $N\ge 1$ such that $b_k=a_k/f^N$ with $a_k\in A$ homogeneous of degree $N$ for all $k$. Then 
$\sum_k a_kf^{k}=0$ in $A_f$. This means for some $m\ge 1$, we have
$$\sum_k a_k f^{k+m}=0 \in A.$$ 
As $\deg(a_kf^{k+m})=N+k+m$, this implies that $a_kf^{k+m}=0$ for all $k$, hence $b_k=a_k/f^N=0$ in $A_{(f)}$ and $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Very impressive:+1. The theorem quoted can also be found in the easier to find other book by Matsumura [*Commutative ring theory*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Commutative_Ring_Theory.html?id=yJwNrABugDEC&redir_esc=y), as Theorem 23.7, page 182.

Comment: A little unimportant remark: it seems to me that $\phi$ is an isomorphism also if $f$ is homogeneous of arbitrary degree $d$. Your proof goes through by just replacing $N$ by $dN$ in a few places. Do you agree ? Anyway I think your answer is a quite  important result that I only knew in the classical case: I'll try to remember your general version in terms of graded rings .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thansk ! The problem with $\deg f>1$ is the surjectivity of $\phi$. If say $\deg f=2$, then in the image of $\phi$ we only have fractions of even degrees (and sums of such fractions). But when $A$ is generated by elements of degree 1 as in the question, then we don't really need to care about element of degree $>1$. But if $A$ is not generated in degree 1, the result on the morphism from the affine cone to the projective scheme is probably false (consider $A=\mathbb C[T_0, T_1, T_2]$ with the variables of respective degrees $2, 3, 5$. Then the projective scheme is singular

Comment: continued: but the affine scheme is regular.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!

Comment: @Jim: you are welcome !

Comment: Dear QiL,  you are right: one cannot prove surjectivity if $deg (f)\gt 1$. I'll leave my preceding comment as a warning to readers tempted to make the same mistake.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: nice to read you again at SE :)